# Ubuntu, IPv6, multihome, e-mail, source selection. Arghhh

Tags: ipv6, smtp, exim

I've been hosting my e-mail forever, and have been also using IPv6 via 6o4 (HE) for some time. Here (South America) IPv6 has been slow in acceptance, so to say, so everything went fine until now. Now I have a new uplink with native IPv6.
But e-mail is a picky app, it needs PTRs and other intricacies so, for the time being, I want to keep my tunnel for SMTP transport (my ISP is thinking about assigning a PTR to me :)
Problem being, I'm not being able to originate with my tunnel IP now. Whenever I originate a connection via IPv6, even if I force via routing the traffic to go over the tunnel, the local IP ends up being the ISP one. And it does not work.

This surfaced on a rejection to an e-mail that was being sent to another HE based MTA!
Which is odd, because we share 2001:67c:/32 and even then I was using a 2800::/16 as origin.

I'm also using a tag (fwmark) to force SMTP to the tunnel. Just in case it matters.
Help ? I've read most of what it seems related, but somehow Ubuntu 20.04 seems not paying attention to gai.conf or address labels. (Added 2001::/16 8 to gai.conf and it does not show using ip addrlabel show, adding with ip addrlabel add... does not change source IP selection)

Another option would be to force exim to use the right address, but I've not seen a way to force one IPv6 address only when using IPv6...

TIA,

-Carlos

Comment: Are you using policy routing (`ip rule`) together with the fwmark?

Comment: Yes, and that seems not to trigger the rule 5 (same network) source address selection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the other option works, I found that exim has the problem resolved and you can define a set of addresses for originating, and IPv4/IPv6 is managed.
So it is working with that plus ip rules for directing SMTP traffic to the tunnel. Why GAI does not work as advertised, that I don't know...